# Add value respectively in each column data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have list which contain 12 data.frame. Each of this data frame is from January to December. This is how look like my list with name Sheet_list in R Studio.

[image]Name          Type

So my question is how to put additional column in each of these tables with the appropriate month? Е.g for January, 1 etc.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Adding columns to a data frame with `mydataframe$newmonth=NA`.

Comment: Yes I can put a new column.But problem here for me is how to populate this new column with appropriate month,for each tables of list ?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: In this list with name "Sheet_list" I have 12 table.All table in the list are data.frame format. So I want to populate each of this table with additional column which contain the name of same table.For e.g First table for January I want to populate whit additional column which contain word "January" or "1" . Is the same for all others tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
l <- list(january=data.frame(id=c(1,2)),
         february=data.frame(id=c(3,4,5)))

l <- purrr::imap(l,function(x,y) mutate(x,month=y))
l
#$`january`
#  id   month
#1  1 january
#2  2 january
#
#$february
#  id    month
#1  3 february
#2  4 february
#3  5 february
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any external packages try:

```
l <- list(january=data.frame(id=c(1,2)),
          february=data.frame(id=c(3,4,5)))

lapply(names(l), function(x){
  l[[x]]$month <<- x
  return(NULL)
})

l
# $`january`
#   id   month
# 1  1 january
# 2  2 january
# 
# $february
#   id    month
# 1  3 february
# 2  4 february
# 3  5 february
```